# Can someone explain to me this code of multiplying two variables using shifts?

Tags: java, algorithm, multiplication

So I have the following code to multiply two variables x and y using left and right shifts.

```
class Multiply {

    public static long multiply(long x,long  y) {
        long sum = 0;
        while(x != 0) {
            if((x & 1) != 0) {
                sum = sum+y;
            }
            x >>>= 1;
            y <<= 1;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long x = 7;
        long y = 5;
        long z = multiply(x,y);
    }
}
```

But I dont understand the logic behind it, I understand that when you do

```
y<<=1
```

You are doubling y, but what does it mean that the number of iterations of the while loop depends on the number of bits x has?

```
while(x != 0)
```

Also why do I only sum if the rightmost bit of x is a 1?

```
   if((x & 1) != 0) {
      sum = sum+y;
   }
```

I've really tried to understand the code but I haven't been able to get my head around the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those of us who remember from school how to multiply two numbers, each with two or more digits, will remember the algorithm:

```
  23
 x45
 ---
 115
 92x
----
1035
```

For every digit in the bottom factor, multiply it by the top factor and add the partial sums together.  Note how we "shift" the partial sums (multiply them by 10) with each digit of the bottom factor.

This could apply to binary numbers as well.  The thing to remember here is that no multiplication (by a factor's digit) is necessary, because it's either a `0` (don't add) or a `1` (add).

```
  101
 x110
-----
  000
 101
101
-----
11110
```

That's essentially what this algorithm does.  Check the least significant bit; if it's a `1`, add in the other factor (shifted), else don't add.

The line `x >>>= 1;` shifts right so that the next bit down becomes the least significant bit, so that the next bit can be tested during the next loop iteration.  The number of loops depends on where the most significant bit `1` in `x` is.  After the last `1` bit is shifted out of `x`, `x` is `0` and the loop terminates.

The line `y <<= 1;` shifts the other factor (multiplies by 2) in preparation for it be possibly added during the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, for every 1 bit in x at position n, it adds 2^n times y to the sum.

It does this without keeping track of n, but rather shuffling the bits x of 1 place right (dividing by 2) every iteration and shuffling the bits of y left (multiplying by 2).

Every time the 0 bit is set, which is tested by `(x & 1) != 0`, the amount to add is the current value of y.

Another reason this works are these equivalences:

```
(a + b) * y == a*y + b*y
x * y == (x/2) * (y*2)
```

which is the essence of what’s going on. The first equivalence allows bit-by-bit addition, and the second allows the opposite shuffling.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>>` is an unsigned right shift which basically fills 0 irrespective of the sign of the number.

So for value `x` in the example 7 (in binary 111) the first time you do `x >>>= 1;` You are making the left most bit a zero so it changes from `111` to `011` giving you 3.

You do it again now you have `011` to `001` giving you 1

Once again and you have `001` to `000` giving you 0

So basically is giving you how many `iterations` before your number becomes zero. (Basically is diving your number in half and it is Integer division)

Now for the `y` value (5) you are adding it to your `sum` and then doubling the value of `y`

so you get:

y = 5   sum = 5

y = 10  sum = 15

y = 20  sum = 35

Only 3 iterations since `x` only needed to shift 3 times.

Now you have your result!  `35`